# How to copy CSV to TABLE if CSV contains too many columns to pre-create table? (Postgress)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, statistics

I want to copy a U.S. Census CSV to a table, however, the CSV header contains well over 200+ columns. How can I tell Postgress SQL to create a table from the CSV using the header as column names?

Comment: You can't with `COPY`. You could use something like [csvsql](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvsql.html) from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). At the `csvsql` there are some other alternatives listed.

Comment: If the above fails write a script to generate the `create table` command.  You will probably have to iterate on this to get the types right.  `https://github.com/frankpd/create_census_tables_sql`  might be a good starting point.